# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE example in python?

Tags: python, mysql, load-data-infile

I am looking for a syntax definition, example, sample code, wiki, etc. for 
executing a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command from python.

I believe I can use mysqlimport as well if that is available, so any feedback (and code snippet) on which is the better route, is welcome.  A Google search is not turning up much in the way of current info

The goal in either case is the same:  Automate loading hundreds of files with a known naming convention & date structure, into a single MySQL table.

David

Comment: Are you using any particular library, like mysql-python or sqlalchemy?

Comment: I can use anything.  Right now, I only have
import MySQLdb in the script.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, using python's MySQLdb, I use this:

```
connection = MySQLdb.Connect(host='**', user='**', passwd='**', db='**')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/my/file' INTO TABLE sometable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\'"
cursor.execute( query )
connection.commit()
```

replacing the host/user/passwd/db as appropriate for your needs.  This is based on the MySQL docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html),  The exact LOAD DATA INFILE statement would depend on your specific requirements etc (note the FIELDS TERMINATED BY, ENCLOSED BY, and ESCAPED BY statements will be specific to the type of file you are trying to read in).

Comment: In my case I was only missing the commit() at the end. Turns out this is required after a LOAD DATA or else the transaction gets lost.

Comment: I wish I could uproot twice for the `connection.commit()` that is not shown in many places

Comment: Precisely. In most places, the `commit` thingy is not mentioned, due to which it simply does not work.

Comment: I would also add the argument to MySQLdb.Connect(local_infile=True)

Answer (score -1):

You can also get the results for the import by adding the following lines after your query:

```
results = connection.info()
```