# PyMySQL error/exception on (file) data load to remote MySQL instance

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, python-db-api

I am using [PyMySQL-0.5.0](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL) and facing an obscure'ish error/exception when loading data from a file to a remote MySQL instance. Upon executing a 'load data local infile ...' statement, I am seeing an exception that says: `The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`.

Any clues, if this operation is supported in PyMySQL at all(and/or if this is supported in some other version)

PS:

1) Error details:

```
2012-05-17 11:05:24,524 - 8988 - DEBUG - Loading table table_2012_05_16 
from file: /path/to/data/file_2012-05-16
2012-05-17 11:05:24,524 - 8988 - DEBUG - Executing update: load data local 
infile '/path/to/data/file_2012-05-16' into table table_2012_05_16(@dummy, c1, 
c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7);
2012-05-17 11:05:24,528 - 8988 - ERROR - Exception while executing update: 
<class 'pymysql.err.InternalError'> - (1148, u'The used command is not allowed 
with this MySQL version')
```

2)  [MySQL docs on the 'load data local infile...' support/syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

3) This data load works fine if I use the mysql client(i.e. IMHO there shouldn't be any impediments - permissions, privileges, what-have-you - to this load):

```
load_machine:~$ mysql -htarget_machine.baz -ufoo -pbar db -e "load data local 
infile '/path/to/data/file_2012-05-16' into table table_2012_05_16(@dummy, c1, 
c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7)"

load_machine: ~$ mysql -htarget_machine.baz -ufoo -pbar db -e "select count(*) 
from table_2012_05_16;"
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 38563191 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data-local.html):

> If [`LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) is disabled, either in the server or the client, a client that attempts to issue such a statement receives the following error message:
>
> ```
> ERROR 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
> ```

PyMySQL does not yet support `LOAD DATA LOCAL`.  It has been a medium-priority defect on [their bug tracker](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/issues/62) for over 10 months, nobody yet assigned to fix it, no milestone set.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234705/623041) for how to perform a `LOAD DATA LOCAL` using Python's MySQLdb instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. Guess PyMySQL is a no-go. Will likely just programmatically invoke mysql client. MySQLdb seems kind of a hassle - build dependencies and such. Would be great if PyMySQL would patch this.

Answer (score 8):

PYMySQL does support `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` but you must enable it in the database connection parameters. Example:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='username', password='password', database='databasename', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, local_infile=True)
```

The default [is set to `False`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L535).

Comment: Thanks. It saved my day. :)

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me after including `local_infile=True`

Answer (score 3):

PyMySQL supports `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` as of version 0.6.4