# Make 10k queries SQL faster

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform over than 10k queries to mysql server from Python and here is my prepared query statement

```
UPDATE `rates` 
SET `in`=%s, `out`=%s, `amount`=%s, `minamount`=%s, `maxamount`=%s 
WHERE `from`='EXMRUB' AND `to`='YAMRUB' AND `id_site`= 1
```

The problem is that it runs really slow, I mean it takes about a 5 minute to perform 10k updates, how can I modify, my query to make it faster?

Comment: do you have indexes?

Comment: You may try adding an index on the combination of the three columns which appear in the `WHERE` clause.  There is no guarantee that MySQL would use this index though while updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id_site` is your table's primary key, you could [use a little MySQL trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/335858) in combination with [`executemany`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46548796/335858) to speed up the update:

```
INSERT INTO rates (id_site, `in`, `out`, amount, minamount, maxamount)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `in`=VALUES(`in`)
,   `out`=VALUES(`out`)
,   amount=VALUES(amount)
,   minamount=VALUES(minamount)
,   maxamount=VALUES(maxamount);
```

`executemany` is very important, because it makes sure that the loop is not done on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up each individual query with an index on ``` (``from``, ``to``, ``id_site``) ```.

However, you are probably better off loading the data into a separate table in the database and then doing the update in a single statement, using `join`.

Comment: I really don't understand JOIN's and INNER's so it would be really great if you show a little example with my query

Comment: Also: Please _don't_ name your columns using keyword like `FROM` and `TO`